# How to use a @FeignClient to map a HAL JSON _embedded collection

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, spring-cloud-netflix, feign, hal-json

We're trying to use a spring-cloud `@FeignClient` to call the HAL-JSON REST API of a microservice from another microservice. The service is implemented with Spring Data Rest, Spring Boot 1.4, with Hateoas enabled by default.

Using a dedicated DTO on the client side, all the simple properties are properly mapped, but the HAL-specific `_embedded` collection is ignored.

As taken primarly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515483/feign-and-hal-resources), we implemented a custom Feign `Decoder` with a corresponding `ObjectMapper`, using the often mentioned `Jackson2HalModule`, but this still does not solve our issue.

**You can reproduce the issue with [this sample project](https://github.com/megli/feign-hateoas)**, where the problem is described in more detail.

We appreciate any help or hints on this problem! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to understanding how to deserialize this is that your `Customer` is the `Resources` class that is embedding the relations. So you need to deserialize it as `Resources` in order for the `HalResourcesDeserializer` to pick it up.

I got it to work this way.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer extends Resources<Resource<Relation>> {

    public static enum Type {
        PERSON, INSTITUTION
    }

    private String displayName;

    private Integer rating;

    private Type type;

    public Collection<Resource<Relation>> getRelations() {
        return this.getContent();
    }
}
```

This still looks a little odd and I am not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: @megli did that help?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am responding to an old question, but in my experience, I had to add  `@EnableHyperMediaSupport` to my main/any configuration class to resolve this issue. You can try that and verify if it works for you.

Comment: A more affirmative writing like 'You have to add ..... to....' will help to not confuse this answer as 'not an answer'

Comment: @Steve, Thank you for your feedback. When someone spends their time to show me how I could do better, I consider it a gift. I have modified my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: I was telling you this because your answer has been caught by the BOT that looks for the 'not an answer' evidences. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50800235#50800235 We have already signalled this as a 'false positive' but still....